# UpdatePanel and JQuery UI/Tabs selected tab

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, updatepanel

I have a server side method that can take long time. I decided to display a loading process modal and for that I used this [tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/guillermo/archive/2008/02/24/ajax-how-to-create-a-quot-processing-quot-modal-window-using-updateprogress-and-modalpopup-asp-net-ajax-controls.aspx). It works fine, but my problem is the following.

I'm using jQuery UI/Tab on the same page and it contains two tabs. On postback all UI loses styles. As I understood, the problem is in `UpdatePanel`, and the solutions suggested is to use the function `pageLoad()`. But it solved my problem partially, because the last selected tab is not persisted on postback.

It worked fine before implementing the loading model process and I used the following :

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        show: function() {
            var sel = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'selected');                                               
            $("#<%= hidLastTab.ClientID %>").val(sel);
            $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "disabled", [<%= hidDisTab.Value %>] );                         
        },
        selected: <%= hidLastTab.Value %>     
    }); 
});
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: How did you resolved this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem and I sorted out using the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(load_lazyload);
    load_lazyload();
}

function load_lazyload() {
    //here you need to add the jquery functions related to the tabs, as well as other jquery code you may have
    //i.e.
    $(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
    });
}
```

Hope this helps,

**UPDATE**: Probably, for your specific case, it would be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(load_lazyload);
    load_lazyload();
}

function load_lazyload() {
    $(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs({
            show: function() {
                var sel = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'selected');                                               
                $("#<%= hidLastTab.ClientID %>").val(sel);
                $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "disabled", [<%= hidDisTab.Value %>] );                         
            },
            selected: <%= hidLastTab.Value %>     
        }); 
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Now the UI comes without style and the modal doesn't appear and i get an error saying that the "Modal progress was not defined"
I don't know what's wrong actually.Any idea?

Comment: Is there any suggestions guys?

Comment: Ok. Probably you have more jquery code within the UpdatePanel. All the jquery code needs to be inside the load_lazyload() function unless it is not inside an UpdatePanel.

Comment: actually I'm following that tutorial, and this is the source code : http://weblogs.asp.net/blogs/guillermo/Code/modalExample.zip .There's only one js file within the main form, and no other jquery code inside the UpdatePanel. It contains only ContentTemplate wich contains the definition of my tabs : <div id ="tab"> etc...

Answer (score 0):

You need to register a ClientSideScript that selects the current tab in whatever event/method that is being executed during the postback.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you explain a little bit more?